# Column listing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input:

```
Name         Id

N1            1
N1            3
N1            4
N1            7
N2            2
N2            1
N2            8
N2            5
N3            4
N3            8
N3            5
N3            3
N4            7
N4            7
N4            7
N4            8
```

Output:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
-----------------------
  N1   N2   N3      N4
   1    2    4      7 
   3    1    8      7
   4    8    5      7
   7    5    3      8
```

Help please

Comment: OP has a horrible attitude, see comment below. Please close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is well-defined, but here's a solution:

```
--CREATE TABLE so1008354 (
--  Name1 VARCHAR(10)
--  ,Name2 VARCHAR(10)
--  ,Name3 VARCHAR(10)
--  ,Name4 VARCHAR(10)
--)
--
--INSERT INTO so1008354 (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4) VALUES ( 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4' ) 
--INSERT INTO so1008354 (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4) VALUES ( '1', '2', '4', '7' ) 
--INSERT INTO so1008354 (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4) VALUES ( '3', '1', '8', '7' ) 
--INSERT INTO so1008354 (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4) VALUES ( '4', '8', '5', '7' ) 
--INSERT INTO so1008354 (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4) VALUES ( '7', '5', '3', '8' ) 

SELECT  *
FROM    so1008354

--
;
WITH    unpvt
          AS ( SELECT   col1,
                        col2
               FROM     so1008354 UNPIVOT ( col2 FOR col1 IN ( [Name1], [Name2], [Name3], [Name4] ) ) AS unpvt
             ) ,
        XLate
          AS ( SELECT   col1 AS NameList_pre,
                        col2 AS NameList
               FROM     unpvt
               WHERE    col2 LIKE 'N%'
             ) ,
        Data
          AS ( SELECT   col1 AS NameList_pre,
                        col2 AS Tokens
               FROM     unpvt
               WHERE    col2 NOT LIKE 'N%'
             )
    SELECT  XLate.NameList,
            Data.Tokens
    FROM    Data
            INNER JOIN XLate ON XLate.NameList_pre = Data.NameList_pre
    ORDER BY XLate.NameList,
            Data.Tokens
```

Which gives results:

```
Name1      Name2      Name3      Name4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
N1         N2         N3         N4
1          2          4          7
3          1          8          7
4          8          5          7
7          5          3          8

(5 row(s) affected)

NameList   Tokens
---------- ----------
N1         1
N1         3
N1         4
N1         7
N2         1
N2         2
N2         5
N2         8
N3         3
N3         4
N3         5
N3         8
N4         7
N4         7
N4         7
N4         8

(16 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because according to the microsoft help documents:

::=
        ( aggregate_function ( value_column ) 
        FOR pivot_column 
        IN (  ) 
    )

So unless you are doing some sort of aggregate function you aren't going to just get a pivot of the column using the pivot function.

However, you can do a pivot of the data above with a normal select and a case statement.

Comment: The fastest way for me to solve would be to dynamically create a temp table and then update each column moving across the table.  such that you create dynamic sql to alter a temp table adding a column for each N value you have.

Comment: @nbiswas_123: YOUR SHIFT KEY STICKS! OH NO, IT'S SPEADING!!!111eleven! (Honestly, don't do that. It looks awful.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select N1, N2, N3, N4
from
(select N_Column, N_Values from [your_table]) p
PIVOT MIN(Tokens)
FOR NameList IN ([N1],[N2],[N3],[N4])
) pvt
```

I called the columns N_column and N_Values from your original table [your_table]
Not sure of the actual names.

If you use min, max you can aggregate any value since there is only one.

Comment: Not working.. throwing compilation error. N!..N4 are values not column names

Comment: How do you differenciate the N# values and the other numbers?  All of your columns are called name. You can use the actual column names.

Comment: My mistake. You entered the result first and then the table structure.

Comment: Hi, I think that some misunderstanding is happening. N# are all column[NameList] values and not the column names. So I cannot write 

"Select N1, N2, N3, N4".

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I've used a case statement for this, but the headings will need to be predetermined.

```
SELECT CASE heading
WHEN 'N1' THEN value END AS 'N1'
, CASE heading WHEN 'N2' THEN value END AS 'N2'
, CASE heading WHEN 'N3' THEN value END AS 'N3'
, CASE heading WHEN 'N4' THEN value END AS 'N4'
```

Comment: If you need the first row to be the headings, just add "SELECT 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4' UNION...

Comment: Hi, I think that some misunderstanding is happening. N# are all column[NameList] values and not the column names. So I cannot write "Select N1, N2, N3, N4"

Answer (score 0):

This is called EAV design. If you expect large amounts of data, your performance will be very poor. If that's the case you may want to switch to a table with N1   N2   N3   N4
as columns, abandoning your current design.

Comment: I'm not sure it's EAV, but it sure is wacky!

Answer (score 0):

select 'N1' , Name1
from your_able 
where name1 <> 'N1'
union

select 'N2' , Name2
from your_able 
where name2 <> 'N2'

union

select 'N3' , Name3
from your_able 
where name3 <> 'N3'

union

select 'N4' , Name4
from your_able 
where name4 <> 'N4'

-- the table is not normalized hence this kind of sql is used.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing. However, change UNION to UNION ALL for both better performance and accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

This works but only if N1...N4 all have the same number of Tokens.

```
SELECT 'N1' AS 'Name1', 'N2' AS 'Name2', 'N3' AS 'Name3', 'N4' AS 'Name4'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
        CAST(t1.Tokens AS varchar), 
        CAST(t2.Tokens AS varchar), 
        CAST(t3.Tokens AS varchar), 
        CAST(t4.Tokens AS varchar)

     FROM (

        (SELECT Tokens, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tokens) AS rownum FROM so2 WHERE NameList = 'N1') t1
         JOIN (SELECT Tokens, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tokens) AS rownum FROM so2 WHERE NameList = 'N2') t2 ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum
         JOIN (SELECT Tokens, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tokens) AS rownum FROM so2 WHERE NameList = 'N3') t3 ON t1.rownum = t3.rownum
         JOIN (SELECT Tokens, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tokens) AS rownum FROM so2 WHERE NameList = 'N4') t4 ON t1.rownum = t4.rownum
    )
```